# Returned html page on Ajax success not inheriting assigned javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

To make things simple, lets take this for example. I have a selection of radio buttons and as I select one to submit, it will display a button on a div below in the same page. I used ajax to pass data to which button it will display and also set a parameter to the ajax success which is the whole html page as the return type from a java class. However, as I click the button, the alert window doesn't appear and is not functioning as well.

Javascript

```
$('.submitBtn').click(function(){
alert("Just an Example.");

$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "hello",
    data: "data=" + $('#data').val(),
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('#div').hide();
    },
    success: function(page){
        $('#div').html($(page).find("div").html());
    },
    complete: function(){
        $('#div').show();
    }
});});
```

Update Javascript. Working but repetitive. Other suggestions?

```
$('.submitBtn').click(function(){
alert("Just an Example.");

$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "hello",
    data: "data=" + $('#data').val(),
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('#div').hide();
    },
    success: function(page){
        $('#div').html($(page).find("div").html());
        $('.submitBtn').click(function(){
            alert("Just an Example.");
        });
    },
    complete: function(){
        $('#div').show();
    }
});});
```

Also, the html page is working fine. When I don't make use of ajax, the button is showing an alert window as I click it after the page reloads. However, I want to use ajax for some reasons. Thank you for helping, really appreciate it.

Comment: this is happening because when you reload the page it is submitting the form again

Comment: You have an extra `'` after alert function. Is it a typo or maybe because of that its not working.

Comment: @WisdmLabs can you please elaborate? thank you

Comment: @Harry Bomrah sorry its just a typo when I had written this code here.

Comment: Can you provide your HTML?

Comment: I would think this is where something goes wrong, but i'm unclear on what the problem is.. `$(page).find("div").html()`

Comment: Or do you mean you have a button in the loaded page? Then you need to bind the event again.

Comment: when you reload page the form data is already set

Comment: @Arg0n I think so too, but the div of the loaded page has been modified to what it is expected, my problem is the button doesn't function to show an alert window. I dont know why the button doesnt inherit the javascript function

Comment: @Arg0n In addition, yes I need to bind the event again on the loaded page. Thank you

Comment: @Arg0n I dont think there is problem with `$(page).find("div").html()` coz as @Raven said even the alert window fails to display. It that was a problem then atleast alert would pop out.

Comment: @Raven are you loading `.submitBtn` button using ajax?

Comment: @Harry Bomrah yes, when it is clicked the ajax will run so that i can pass the values without loading the page .Thank you

Comment: @Raven please check my answer. See if it is what you need?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does not know about you changing the DOM. When you do `$(".btn").on("click", ...);` it attaches an eventhandler to the elements with class `btn` that it currently finds. It does not check for future elements with this class and attaches an event to those too.

Therefore, you need to attach the event again when the element(s) is available.

Comment: Can you please check the updated question if I am able to understand what your are referring to. If yes, are there any ways to prevent from having repetitive block of codes .thank you

Comment: Try @HarryBomrah's answer first. If that works, it's great!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting async to false in your case and your alert might work as you are using ajax inside a function async will play its role and might be blocking the alert box.

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
$(document.body).on('click','.submitBtn',function(){
  // your event here.
})
```

Bind this event. you dont ve to rebind the click event again. jquery will automatically bind click event to your `.submitBtn` as soon as it is loaded in the page.

Comment: Will this work even if the function is in an external javascript file, not on a script tag within an html file? thank you

Comment: Yes it will work in a js file too. Just see the jquery should be loaded before your js file is loaded.

Comment: I used them long back ago. You can ask or create another question and i can see if i can help u. :)

Comment: Its actually the same with this situation, the table doesn't apply with the datatable in the loaded page of the ajax success `$('.tablel').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aLengthMenu": [[10, 20, 50, -1], [10, 20, 50, "All"]]
    });`

Comment: `$('.tablel')` is this present at time of page load or you load the html `.tabel` using javascript. and also how do you get the data. Do you get any error?

Comment: It is already presented at the time of page load. I didn't get any error but the table did not apply the datatable functions. As the page goes through the ajax success the datatable was not applied, but when I simply use page load without ajax, it applied. thank you.

Comment: Well its bit confusing. Can you provide a fiddle to make it more clear?

Comment: Can you please check this link Sir? I need your help . Thank you. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33995048/permanently-bind-a-table-id-to-jquery-datatable)