# Permanently bind a table id to jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables, bind

How can I permanently bind a table id to jquery datatable? As I pass the whole html page to an ajax success it doesn't inherit the jquery datatable functions which is already set. The code below functions well but I was forced to repeat the set of codes and I am avoiding that so I want to ask everybody if you could help me bind it permanently or do some other ways. Thank you.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.tbl').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "aLengthMenu": [[10, 20, 50, -1], [10, 20, 50, "All"]]
});
$('.submitBtn').click(function(){
    alert("Just an Example.");

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "hello",
        data: "data=" + $('#data').val(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#div').hide();
        },
        success: function(page){
            $('#div').html($(page).find("div").html());
            $('.tbl').dataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aLengthMenu": [[10, 20, 50, -1], [10, 20, 50, "All"]]
        });
        },
        complete: function(){
            $('#div').show();
        }
    });
});});
```

Comment: What do u get as html in your success function? is it updated table data?

Comment: @Harry Bomrah It displays the table without jquery datable functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, maybe it works

```
  success: function(page){
        $('#div').html($(page).find("div").html());
        $('.tbl').destroy();
        $('.tbl').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aLengthMenu": [[10, 20, 50, -1], [10, 20, 50, "All"]]
    });
```

But i suggest instead of getting data as HTML, you should get it as JSON object and then update the table with the data.

Comment: the js code in the question is running well. the point here is to permanently bind the id of a table to jquery datatable because some other tables are also using the set of datatable script outside the ajax. There should be no datatable script within ajax success.

Comment: No you cant do that as you load ajax on button click. you ve to reinitialize the table again after the data is loaded.\

Comment: I think there is a way. If you have ajax call related to this in your page which gets the data and puts it in table. You can have a callback for global ajax:success event. So everytime there is an ajax call that global event will be called. But if you have any other ajax call then it ll also be executed everytime.

Answer (score 0):

**If** you want to recreate the dataTable you *must* use the `destroy` / `bDestroy` option and replicate the settings. You can hold the settings in a variable like

```
var settings = {
   bDestroy : true, //<---
   "bJQueryUI": true,
   "iDisplayLength": 10,
   "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
   "aLengthMenu": [[10, 20, 50, -1], [10, 20, 50, "All"]]
}
```

and any time you (re) create the table :

```
$('.tbl').dataTable(settings);
```

---

If you not want to recreate the table you can empty the table, parse `page` and inject each `<tr>` `<td>`'s :

Save the dataTable instance in a variable

```
var table = $('#example').dataTable({
```

success handler :

```
success: function(page){
   table.api().clear();
   $(page).find('tbody').find('tr').each(function(tr) {
      var arr = [];
      $(tr).find('td').each(function() { 
         arr.push($(this).html());
      }) 
      table.api().row.add(arr);
   })
   table.api().draw();
}
```

I assume you are using dataTables 1.10.x. If you do, you can skip the `api()` by initalising with `DataTable()`, capital `D`. If you are using dataTables 1.9.x, use table.`fnAddData` and `fnClearTable` instead :

```
success: function(page){
   table.fnClearTable();
   $(page).find('tbody').find('tr').each(function(tr) {
      var arr = [];
      $(tr).find('td').each(function() { 
         arr.push($(this).html());
      }) 
      table.fnAddData(arr);
   })
}
```